# Chrome DevTools not working with the Select element

Tags: html, css

I am working on fixing a style sheet for mobile devices for a website and I am using the DevTools that come built into Chrome for testing purposes. I am using Chrome version 53.0.2785.116 on a Windows operating system right now.

My problem is that, when I'm using the DevTools, the `<select>` elements' expanded section (the part that normally drop's down) is completely off center and appears as a black box.

At first I thought it was something wrong in the style, but I created  new .html file and simply added a `<select>` element to the page and have found the same thing.

I realize that on the actual device the drop down section is displayed differently (as a section at the bottom of the device with the options in a Rolodex type animation); however, I am unable to use the select menu for testing purposes...

Is there any way around this problem?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title></title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <select>
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
        <option>c</option>
        <option>d</option>
        <option>e</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem: [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple select tag with options not working on Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635438/simple-select-tag-with-options-not-working-on-chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For testing purposes you can change the device type from mobile to desktop(touch). This will allow you to get around the issue with the `select` element and mobile emulation.

To enable these options open your developer tools by righting and inspecting the page you are on or press f12. Click on the menu icon (3 dots) to the right of the rotate icon (menu icon below chromes top right) - **Edit**: *see image dots circled in red*.

- Select **Show device type** and **Show device pixel ratio**
- Select Responsive from the first dropdown and input your other device values

To save having to do this all the time you can create a custom device profile

- In the first dropdown select **Edit** then **Add Custom Device**
- **Note:** Edit will only appear if you have already created a custom device type, see the **Edit** below for how to create a custom device for the first time.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**
For Chrome version 53.0.2785.143 for Windows, these are the steps you would take to accomplish adding a custom device type:

1. Navigate to the page you want to test and open the developer tools by hitting F12
   [image]
2. Hit F1 to open the developer tools settings
   [image]
3. Select devices in the settings menu
4. Add a custom device with the same configuration details as the device you want to test and do as described above.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know what version of Chrome you are using but the instructions on how to add a custom device did not line up with my version of Chrome. I had to: open developer tools, click the menu ("..." button) in the developer tools, click settings, select devices from the settings menu and go from there. This helps me tremendously. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help, odd im using the most current version of chrome on windows aswell: 53.0.2785.143 wonder why they are different

Comment: @Frinavale Think because I already had a custom device set i have the option to click edit in the first dropdown where you select the devices and it takes you straight to that page.